# Is there a way to use concise static dispatch inside a loop in Rust?

Tags: generics, rust, idioms, code-duplication

I have a for loop where the first iteration is a special case. The only difference is the type of one variable even though they both implement the same traits. I want to know if and how I can make it more concise.

There is a concrete type called `Concrete`. It implements a trait `FooTrait<T>` with method `foo<T>(&mut self, modifier: T)` for various Ts. Notably, FooTrait<&Concrete> is implemented.

I have a function `bar()` that looks something like this:

```
pub fn bar(slice_len, initial: &Concrete) {
    let concrete_slice[Concrete; slice_len] = initialize_slice();
    let mut carry: &Concrete = initial;
    for i in 0..concrete_slice.len() {
        concrete_slice[i].foo(carry);
        carry = &concrete_slice;
    }
    epilogue(carry);
}
```

I want to allow it to take different types of initial values by using generics. (note: the function must be able to accept anonymous types because some of the types are private in a separate crate.)

```
pub fn bar<T>(slice_len, initial: T)
where
    Concrete: FooTrait<T>
{
    let concrete_slice[Concrete; slice_len] = initialize_slice();
    if slice_len > 0 {
        concrete_slice[0].foo(initial);
        let mut carry: &Concrete = &concrete_slice[0];
        for i in 1..concrete_slice.len() {
            concrete_slice[i].foo(carry);
            carry = &concrete_slice[i];
        }
        epilogue(carry);
    } else {
        epilogue(initial);
    }
}
```

Obviously, this is a generalized and simplified example, and my actual code is more complex. I would rather it look closer to the first one than the second one for readability.

I know if I want to make a wrapper around multiple different types I can use enum. However, if there is a way to use enums without making the code less concise, I don't know about it. I also know trait objects are a thing, but those have runtime costs. Is there a better idiom for this?

Comment: I don't believe you can do that concisely like your first code sample. You *might* be able to hide it in a clever macro but I feel that would be more obscuring than clarifying.

Comment: Even if you could hide it behind an enum, the runtime performance cost of branching on every iteration is likely not worth it.

Comment: @cdhowie Would -O3 fix that?

Comment: How? Optimization can't remove a necessary branch ⁉

Comment: @Nic I mean it's possible, if the compiler were to unroll the first iteration of the loop and then prove that all following iterations always take one particular branch arm. You'd have to look at the generated assembly to be sure.

Comment: @cafce25 It could potentially realize that the code is equivalent to my second code block shown. There are necessary branches in that, but not as much as a literal interpretation of enum method.